# concurrent transaction management in EJB/JPA

Tags: jpa, ejb

I am working on EJB 3.0 where entity beans are managed by JPA.My question is if two or more user will try to insert in same table using same form same time, how JPA will handle that situation.

Comment: what is the primary key of the table? Is the primary key auto generated by sequence or composite business key or what? If the key is auto generated, concurrent insert usually do not need JPA to take any special action.

Comment: primary key is a sequence from oracle.but my curiosity is how JPA will manage if it is not auto generated but single varchar column as primary key,or for sequence how it will manage. "how"?

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Sequence pre-allocator will pre-generate and assign the key to your entity whenever a new entity becomes persistent. The detail of how sequence is working has nothing to do with your question. If key is a single varchar column, then underlying DB will guarantee that there will not be duplicates with same Key. @JB Nizet has already explained that this is part of **ACID**, and also ACID is guaranteed by underlying DB but not JPA.

Answer (score 1):

It will manage it just fine, by using database transactions. If two threads try to create the same row (i.e. with the same primary key) at the same time, one will succeed, and the other will get an exception from the database, which will cause a rollback of its transaction. That means that all the other inserts, updates and deletes made in the same transaction will also be rollbacked, or cancelled if you prefer, leaving the database in a coherent state. That's the A in [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

If two threads insert two different rows at the same time in the same table, then the database will handle that just fine, and both rows will be inserted.